# iOS scroll get stuck sometimes

Tags: ios, css

I came across a weird behavior in safari on iphone (iOS 9.2)

If you see this page http://jsbin.com/vofubidaxe on desktop, there are 3 images of panda and you can scroll it

But if you see it on iphone safari, sometimes (not all the times) you can't scroll it. The scroll seems to get stuck (not sure if stuck is the right word to describe the behavior)

Edit here http://jsbin.com/vofubidaxe/edit?html,css,output

The gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/938fc5f84222d8ed06cdcb7f6092da8d

The nav tag has a `position: fixed`, if this is removed, the scroll resumes normal.

Sorry if this is a known bug in safari. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `position:fixed` on an element removes it from the document DOM - so the panda images do not render on the actual document.

It sometimes 'get stuck' because probably your touched bubble up to the document - so flicking forces the document to scroll and not the fixed element.

The solution would be to remove the relative element and give a height to the fixed parent element - if you want it full height, try adding `top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0` and then overflow it.

However, this would work on an iphone, but would cause issues to other devices - android, windows phones, etc because of poor overflown element support.

Answer (score 0):

use this it will definitely work. Add the style in your parent tag

style="display: block; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"

overflow-y: scroll;

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;